# Payment Method Save Config Button Not work magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

[image]

Payment Method Save Config Button Not work magento 1

Comment: first, open all the fieldsets in the page and check if there is a field that does not pass validation. If all fields are valid, check the js console for errors.

Comment: can you explain details with source file path.its help to me

Comment: explain what? I have no idea what the problem is. I just gave you 2 leads to identify the problem